# IntelliJ Idea 12, 13 - Debug info unavailable in Scala - SBT Project

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm debugging my Scala SBT project in IntelliJ Idea 13.
However, it seems to me that I'm getting less info on my local variables as I used to.

Two Problems:
(minor) First of all, hovering over a variable doesn't show me its current value (I need to have alt pressed, even though I've checked the corresponding setting in

Debugger > Data Views > Auto tooltips for values .

(major) Second: See this screenshot:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3517/kdtr4k6j_png.htm

Once I enter the while loop, I don't get any information on the current value of the variables as defined above (e.g. RkNN_q). Why is that?
If I remember correctly, this used to be different.

I have set the Scala Debugging info level to: "Source, line number and local variable information".

(Same problems occur in IntellIj Idea 12)

Thank you very much in advance for your help!